# How to store data permanently in AIML?

Tags: android, aiml

I am currently working on a Chatbot on android platform and want to store the information of the user in the AIML itself. I tried using AIML tags  and  but it remembers the data temporarily, Once the application is closed or restarted the information stored in AIML is erased.

Please tell me a way to retain the information for subsequent sessions. I am using Program AB library for chatting

Answer (score 0):

If you are using aiml 2.0 then use the learnf tag rather than the learn tag.

The learnf tag writes the new knowledge to file which will be reloaded on restart but learn tag is none persistant

K